# Phoenix server doesn't render css and images with Docker

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix, and having to work in CI/CD environment I'm trying to figure out how to use Phoenix with Docker.

I've tried various tutorials and videos out there, many of them doesn't work, but those who do work, they have the same result.

[image]

Phoenix server doesn't seems to find some resources (the assets folder?).

But inside my Dockerfile I'm copying the entire app folder, and I can confirm that /assets is inside the container by attaching to it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM elixir:alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base git

WORKDIR /app

RUN mix local.hex --force && \
    mix local.rebar --force

COPY . .

RUN mix do deps.get, deps.compile

CMD ["mix", "phx.server"]
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  db:
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    image: 'postgres:11-alpine'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - 'pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MIX_ENV: dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Steps I'm doing to create the containers and running the server:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run web mix ecto.create
docker-compose up
```

The database is created successfully in the db container.
What can be happening here?

Sorry if it's straightforward, I don't use Docker for a while and I still didn't understood Phoenix boilerplate completely.

If you know some good resources about Docker and CI/CD pipelines with Phoenix, I also appreciate so I can study it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to build the assets. `npm install --prefix assets` This needs to be done after after `mix deps.get` but can be done after the `mix deps.compile` which isn't really needed. You can start the server after `mix deps.get` and it will compile the deps and your app automatically.

Comment: Thank you Steve, sorry for taking long to accept your answer. Although I knew that your answer was right, it still didn't worked but today. That's because node-sass was failing to compile. You need a specific version of node (node@14) to compile the assets and this isn't written anywhere but on a (closed!) issue from January. It's very frustrating to see it failing, googling around and not finding any information about why it fails, and it's wrong IMO to close an issue that still an issue.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue with latest nodejs. I'm using node@14 also.